# Set Cursor position to right after selection in word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, cursor-position

I have code that creates fields on a word document based on selection, but when it is done it has the field selected.  I want to select the position right after the field.  So if there is a FIELD_ with _ being the position right after the field, it is what I want to select.

I found this:

```
Dim newSelect As Long: newSelect = Selection.End + 1
```

to get the Character position but then how do I select based on character position? Or is there another method to acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls try.

```vb
Selection.Collapse Word.wdCollapseEnd
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Selection.Collapse method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.collapse?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158662757)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

[image]